# Extra <p> tag when outputting WordPress "Read More" link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've written a function that outputs a variable blog post "Read More" link, and I've just noticed that it also renders an extra empty `<p>` tag at the end:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
  global $post;
  if (is_page( '39' ) ) {
    return ' [&#8230;]<div id="blog-newest-continue"><a class="moretag btn btn-primary btn-xl wow bounceIn" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '#post-content' . '">Continue reading <span>&rarr;</span></a></div>';
  }
   else {
    return ' [&#8230;]<div id="blog-newest-continue"><a class="moretag btn btn-primary btn-md" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Continue reading <span>&rarr;</span></a></div>';
  }
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
 <h2 class="section-heading">Blog</h2>
 <h3><a href="http://localhost:8888/2016/06/hello-wordpress-world/">Text</a></h3>
 <header id="blog-newest-byline" class="post-byline">
  <div><span class="post-time"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o"></i>Jun 2nd, 2016 at 16:18 EDT</span> <span class="post-tags"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tags"></i> <a href="http://localhost:8888/tag/web-design/" rel="tag">web design</a>, <a href="http://localhost:8888/tag/web-development/" rel="tag">web development</a>, <a href="http://localhost:8888/tag/wordpress/" rel="tag">wordpress</a></span>   <span class="post-comments"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments-o"></i> <a href="http://localhost:8888/2016/06/hello-wordpress-world/#comments"><fb:comments-count href="http://localhost:8888/2016/06/hello-wordpress-world/" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class=" fb_comments_count_zero"><span class="fb_comments_count">0</span></fb:comments-count>
   comments</a>
   </span>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="post-thumb row no-gutter"><a href="http://localhost:8888/2016/06/hello-wordpress-world/"><img width="700" height="700" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/test.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt=""></a></div>
 <p
   id="blog-newest-excerpt">Text</p>
  <div id="blog-newest-continue"><a class="moretag btn btn-primary btn-xl wow bounceIn" href="#post-content" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: bounceIn;">Continue reading <span>→</span></a></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I've also noticed that it only happens on the homepage (page 39) condition and if I leave the `return` empty, there's no extra `<p>` tag. Separately, I'm also using `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` to remove extra `<p>` tags from the WYSIWYG editor.

What could be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you use the return value from the `else` condition? Can you also include the generated HTML?

Comment: @FluffyKitten The `else` condition doesn't render anything on the affected page, and on the page it does, there's no extra `<p>` tag. I've updated my question with the HTML. Thanks

Comment: What I means was: if you replace the `return '`...`';` line for page 39 with the `return '`...`';` from the else, does it add the `<p></p>` then? Also, I don't see the `...` ([&#8230;]) in the HTML.. I wonder is it something to do with it being stripped out? Does it appear on the other pages?